# Can't download drivers from local mirrors

Tags: drivers, updates, mirrors

I was downloading optional drivers for my NVidia GeForce RTX 2060 Super 8gb from software center, then progress stopped and an error popped out that said

[driver url] is not (yet) availiable

I tried using VPN, but got same issue.

After I changed "Download from" to Main server, drivers downloaded without problem.

It was previously set to mirror in Iran, Islamic republic of. Asiatech server

Is it a bug or I did something wrong? I got this issue many times before on other devices too

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu main server is reasonably fast and it is updated every day, unlike some local mirrors that sometimes wait to update their packages for 1-2 weeks or even longer. I sometimes use the Ubuntu main server for this exact reason, and I have never encountered any problems with it due to unavailable software updates.